# gRPC read method options before launching server

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm currently trying to add scopes to secure my gRPC methods exposition and I'm using custom scopes for each methods.

Here is my scope class:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";
package grpc.proto.scopes;

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.MethodOptions {
    string scopes = 50000;
}
```

And I'm using it on my service scheme:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";
import "grpc/proto/scopes.proto";

package service;

service Service1 {
    rpc Get(Request) returns (Response) {
        option(grpc.proto.scopes.scopes) = "service1.feature.read";
    }
    rpc Post(Request) returns (Response) {
        option(grpc.proto.scopes.scopes) = "service1.feature.write";
    }
}
```

But my problem is the following:

```golang
server := grpc.NewServer([...my interceptor which uses my scopes...])
// <-- I must initialize my server with my interceptor but I need to have an access to the registry to retrieve scopes
proto.RegisterService1Server(server, s) // <-- Schemes are available on registry only on this line
```

I cannot initialize my scopes interceptor with `proto` shemes' scope because they are available only when they are registered on the server. But I can't initialize my server without my interceptor, so I'm blocked.
I can handle scope on the fly inside my interceptor with `protoregistry.GlobalFiles.FindDescriptorByName` but it will decrease performances.

Is there any way to get my shemes' scopes before initializing my server?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you're describing - https://gist.github.com/nick-jones/19a2f5ff4be267474f85a238406c2c1e - as long as the packages containing the proto generated code are imported, it looks like the types and options are available.

Comment: Oh yes, was a miss-understanding, on my unit tests, my interceptor didn't retrieve scopes until I was using `proto.RegisterService1Server`. So I thought that I was the way to have it on the registry.
But in fact importing it is enough. Thank you!